# Using google finance currency conversion for codeigniter.. Worked fine for 2-4 months but now suddenly conversion is getting disable in between?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

**Using google finance & yahoo finance currency conversion for codeigniter.. Worked fine for 2-4 months but now suddenly conversion getting disable in between??**

My Code Snippet (Helper File Code):

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('convertCurrency')) {

    function convertCurrency($amount,$from_Currency,$to_Currency) {
        $amount = urlencode($amount);
        $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
        $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
        $get = @file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
        $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
        $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
        $converted_currency = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
        return number_format($converted_currency,2,'.','');
    }
}
```

Calling that function in controllers as well as view files as below:

```
<?php echo convertCurrency($amount, "INR", "USD");?>
```

**Worked well for 2-4 months but now its getting disable in between??**

**I also tried it with CURL, but not getting response from link.**

please suggest me proper idea??

Comment: What's your php version ?

Comment: local php version: 5.6.3, live php version: 5.6.34, define('CI_VERSION', '3.0rc');

Comment: It seems that URL has been removed. Same problem for me. Last comments here also say the same: https://gist.github.com/daveismyname/8067095. Search another converter

Comment: if anybody know then please suggest me some free and convenient currency conversion links for php/codeigniter??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google finance converter stopped working or changed its url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324112/google-finance-converter-stopped-working-or-changed-its-url)

Answer (score 1):

Google has shutdown that service in these days.

The only alternative solutions I've found are :

- <s>http://www.xe.com/it/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=EUR</s> Warning : Automated extraction of rates is prohibited under the Terms of Use of xe.com
- free to use API (with some limits) https://currencylayer.com/

See also this response with other solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10040996/1798842

Comment: https://currencylayer.com/ does not support to rupees as source currency

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. Give a try :)

```
$url = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?
     Amount=1&From=USD&To=INR";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
   "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = explode('uccResultAmount', $rawdata);
@$data = explode('uccToCurrencyCode', $data[1]);

$amount = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/', '', $data[0]);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use:

```
$res = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=CAD");
```

it is google calculator and will work.

Now you have to parse this response:

```
$res = explode("<span class=bld>",$res);
$res = explode("</span>",$res[1]);
$rate= preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
```

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=CAD): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` - Getting this error