# Google Finance api giving 403 error

Tags: google-api, currency, finance

I am using google finance api for conversion of currency based on real rate conversion,

The API what I am using is given below:

**https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=INR**

It was working till yesterday but from today it's throwing 403 response code.
Can anyone help me on that or Is this url changed??

Thanks

Comment: look at this answer, it could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google finance converter stopped working or changed its url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324112/google-finance-converter-stopped-working-or-changed-its-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Google just silently deprecated `finance.google.com`, redirecting it to `google.com/search`. Probably better to switch to a more reliable currency exchange rates provider. In my case, I've switched to EU Central Bank.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this with the updated google URL for currency converter.

[Click here](https://www.techbuy.in/google-finance-api-currency-converter-not-working-updated-link-check-currency-converter/) to check the solution now.

just do update your existing link with this and you can solve your problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Google finance API is just moved to new URL.** You can check the solution here:

[Error in Google finance API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429015/error-in-google-finance-api/49519518#49519518)