# PyCurrency_Converter: call to convert causes 403 forbidden response

Tags: python

Mod security blocks me from accessing a URL.

I have tried using other methods from this website, but none seem to work as I use an import called `PyCurrency-Calculator`

```py
import PyCurrency_Converter
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PyCurrency_Converter.convert(1, 'USD', 'A$')
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Downloads/list of currencies.py", line 7, in <module>
    PyCurrency_Converter.convert(1, 'USD', 'A$')
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyCurrency_Converter\PyCurrency.py", 
line 48, in convert
    return PyCurrency.convert(amount, _from, _to)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyCurrency_Converter\PyCurrency.py", 
line 31, in convert
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: I think `PyCurrency_Converter` gets its data from a webpage, which is probably down or not accepting requests for some reason. I think a fix should come from the developer of the library. However, there are alternatives for a currency converter. Try [CurrencyConverter](https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/).

Comment: The underlying request would look like [this](https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=A$) its a [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) and error text is `We're sorry...... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.` Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366919/google-finance-api-giving-403-error). PyCurrency_Converter is hardcoded to use that google finance uri, so you probably want to use another library or make the http request yourself to another service.

Answer (score 0):

`PyCurrency_Converter` makes a call google finance under the hood ([code](https://github.com/SiddharthSaxena/PyCurrency-Converter/blob/master/PyCurrency_Converter/PyCurrency.py)). This service is no longer available and so the library needs to be modified to use a different service.

What you can do is find an alternative web based api and call that (I have no recommendation). As you can see the code for `PyCurrency_Converter` is quite short, so it will be simple to take and adapt it to another currency conversion api or to use requests or urllib to just do the requests yourself.