# Facing error while getting currency exchange rate from Google Finance API

Tags: currency-exchange-rates

Below code was working fine on Production from last few months.
Recently it started breaking.

Yesterday it was giving HTTP error issue for `file_get_contents` function.
Today, On Execution it shows Undefined Offset error.

I am not sure what has changed for Finance Google API.

```
public function getJPYtoUSDExchangeRate(){
        $from    = 'JPY';
        $to    = 'USD';
        $amount  = 1;
        $data = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to");
        preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
        $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1][0]);
        return number_format(round($converted, 3),2);
}
```

Comment: Please tag the language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google finance converter stopped working or changed its url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324112/google-finance-converter-stopped-working-or-changed-its-url)

Comment: Thank you Benjamin Smith. I tried changing the URL to https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter and it's working now. 
Details are present here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324112/google-finance-converter-stopped-working-or-changed-its-url

Comment: Changing URL to finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter was worked few weeks and now again it's breaking from last 2 days.
Anything changed again? Is there any better way to get Currency Exchange Rate?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution for this with the updated google URL for currency converter
https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the link, google updated the api link recently, and I found success once on checking 10 times to the existing link.
Try changing to this link 
https://www.google.com/finance/converter

see this
https://www.techbuy.in/google-finance-api-currency-converter-not-working-updated-link-check-currency-converter/

Comment: Thank you iamal for quick response. Changing to https://www.google.com/finance/converter is not working. I changed it to https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter and looks like it's working now. I am not sure what was causing the error. But I will still wait for few days before pushing the changes on Production. Thank you.