# Google currency converter no longer working

Tags: currency-exchange-rates

It appears that Google Finance Currency Converter has stopped working altogether. A week ago I started getting these email notifications from my Magento 1.9.2 store:

Currency update warnings:
WARNING: Cannot retrieve rate from https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=GBP&to=EUR.
WARNING: Cannot retrieve rate from https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=GBP&to=USD.

Those URLs are indeed no longer valid. Does anyone know if there are new URLs we can use, or do we need to configure a different service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google finance converter stopped working or changed its url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324112/google-finance-converter-stopped-working-or-changed-its-url)

Comment: Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429015/error-in-google-finance-api/49519518#49519518

Comment: https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/ and https://www.google.com/finance both are not working now, do you know new URL?

Answer (score 4):

This link is not working anymore.

```
 protected $_url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&to={{CURRENCY_TO}}';
```

I researched and found this codes.

Find this file:

```
app/code/local/Payserv/GoogleFinance/Model/Google.php
```

Replace the codes with this:

```
class Payserv_GoogleFinance_Model_Google extends Mage_Directory_Model_Currency_Import_Abstract {

protected $_url = 'http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q={{CURRENCY_FROM}}_{{CURRENCY_TO}}';

protected $_messages = array();

protected function _convert($currencyFrom, $currencyTo, $retry=0) {
    $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_FROM}}', $currencyFrom, $this->_url);
    $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_TO}}', $currencyTo, $url);
    try {
         $resultKey = $currencyFrom.'_'.$currencyTo;
         $response = file_get_contents($url);
         $data = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($response);
         $results = $data['results'][$resultKey];
         $queryCount = $data['query']['count'];
         if( !$queryCount &&  !isset($results)) {
            $this->_messages[] = Mage::helper('directory')->__('Cannot retrieve rate from %s.', $url);
            return null;
        }
       return (float)$results['val'];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($retry == 0) {
            $this->_convert($currencyFrom, $currencyTo, 1);
        } else {
            $this->_messages[] = Mage::helper('directory')->__('Cannot retrieve rate from %s', $url);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I check this morning and suddenly the URL link is not working. I will ping you if I can find any other link.

Comment: thank you so much!  finally got a free converter api without the need to login

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be intermittent (it shows if I load a page 10 times or so, but only once every 10 clicks). But I've personally started configuring other services. I am using bank API's (currently a Swedish one so it might not help you). But check with your bank, they usually have APIs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Google doesn't offer this service anymore.

The main alternative looks to be:

- [Fixer.io API](https://github.com/fixerAPI/fixer#readme)
- [Currencylayer API](https://currencylayer.com/documentation)

Both offers 1000 request for free a month ( you need to create an account on their homepage )

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391430/716435

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't provide the currency converter API anymore. There are several alternative APIs offering currency conversion data. Some have been mentioned in posts already (Fixer, Currencylayer...)

Another option is [SWOP currency exchange rate API](https://swop.cx/), a fast, easy to use, reliable and transparent foreign exchange rate API made from developers for developers. Full disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of SWOP :)

- The SWOP API offers current and historical rates for 180+ currencies. They are gathered directly from trusted sources (various Central Banks and other important banks).
- The SWOP API has two endpoints, GraphQL and REST/JSON, for developer convenience.
- There's a free plan allowing 1,000 requests per month.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the link, google updated the api link recently, and I found success once on checking 10 times to the existing link. Try changing to this link https://www.google.com/finance/converter

see this https://www.techbuy.in/google-finance-api-currency-converter-not-working-updated-link-check-currency-converter/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem from last week. But new url solved my problem and now currency conversion working fine.
try this:
https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter

Answer (score -1):

Google's finance URL doesn't seem to work for now, I have prepared a workaround to use MSN Money (Microsoft's) API. It returns JSON so you can consume it using any programing language, I have put sample using PHP:

```
    function msn($from, $to, $amount) {

    $url = 'https://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartDataV5?symbols=245.20.'.strtoupper($from).strtoupper($to).'LITE&chartType=1y';
    $request = curl_init();
    $timeOut = 0;

    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($request));
    curl_close($request);

    $rate = array_last($response[0]->Series)->P;

    return $rate * $amount;
}
```

The above function accepts the currency that you currently have, the target currency and amount. Send's a GET request to MSN URL and parses the JSON to get today's exchange rate. Finally, it multiplies the rate with your amount to convert it to the target currency.

I hope this solves your need, the code has a lot of rooms for optimization I just gave you a simple implementation
For example, you can save the exchange rate in your database and use that rate for one day this way you will only call the API once a day.